# Find the domain and range of a quadratic

Tags: functions, quadratics

$$F(x)=\frac {x^2+ax+1}{x^2+x+1}$$
Find the complete set of values of 'a' such that $F(x)$ is onto
And f(x) maps from real numbers to real numbers.

Comment: Domain is set of all real numbers.

Comment: For 'onto', try and solve $x$ such that $F(x)=y$ for some arbitrary $y$. This will place a constraint on $a$.

Answer (score 0):

The domain is when $ x^{2}+x+1 \neq 0 $ And you know that this function is never 0 so you will get your domain: $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: How do we know that the numerator goes from -infinity to + infinity

Comment: It doesn't... $x^2+ax+1$ will always have a minimum.